# replace Semi-colon into comma in repeat

Tags: multi-select

I have a multiselect picklist its fetch data separate into semicolon i want to replace semi colon into comma.

SEE Image Marked yellow
[image]

class code

```
public class Job_Application{

    public Id JobID{get;set;}
    public List<Job__c> Query{get;set;}

    public Job_Application(ApexPages.StandardController sc){

        JobID = sc.getId();  
        System.debug('----Job ID ----- '+JobID); 
        fetchRecords();
    }

    public void fetchRecords(){
        Query = [SELECT Id, (SELECT id, Name, Experience__c, Qualification__c, Score__c, Spoken_Language__c, Technical__c FROM Job_Applicants__r) FROM Job__c WHERE Id =:JobID];
    }
}
```

VF PAge

```
<apex:page standardController="Job__c" extensions="Job_Application" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <head>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS080, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
          <style type="text/css">
                 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    width: 6px;
                    height: 8px;
                }

                ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
                    background-color: #a8b7c7;
                    border-radius: 20px;
                }

                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
                    height: 30px;
                    background-color: #e0e5ee;
                    border-radius: 20px;
                }

                .back{
                    background : rgb(0,162,232);
                }

           </style>
      </head>
      <div class="slds">
          <apex:form >
                  <apex:outputPanel id="RepeatREcord">

                          <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--fixed-layout">
                            <apex:repeat value="{!Query}" var="fetch2">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!fetch2.Job_Applicants__r}" var="fetch">
                                        <tr class="back">
                                            <th>Applicant Name</th>
                                            <th>Experience</th>
                                            <th>Qualification</th>
                                            <th>Score</th>
                                            <th>Spoken Language</th>
                                            <th>Technical Language</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> {!fetch.Name} </td>
                                            <td> {!fetch.Experience__c} </td>
                                            <td> {!fetch.Qualification__c} </td>
                                            <td> {!fetch.Score__c} </td>
                                            <td> {!fetch.Spoken_Language__c} </td>
                                           <td> {!fetch.Technical__c} </td> 
                                       </tr>
                                   </apex:repeat>
                            </apex:repeat> 
                        </table>
                  </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:form>
      </div>
  </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to replace the semi-colon?  What part of that didn't work?  Please update your question with this extra information rather than creating a long comment thread.

Comment: in qualification column output show BCA ; MCA ( i want to replace this ; into comma(,) and show result like this BCA , MCA 

Qualification column values are multi select picklist type

Comment: Can you read?  Why are you just repeating your original question in the comments?

Comment: You can save `Qualification__c` records with `,` delimited, or you have to have a wrapper class to bind data into front end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text)` function to replace semi colon with comma.

In your case, replace this line

```
<td> {!fetch.Qualification__c} </td>
```

With this line to change the Qualification text.

```
<td> {!substitute(fetch.Qualification__c, ';', ',')} </td>
```

Do similar change for `Technical Language`. Hope this helps.